# JavaScript split string with backslash

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I get from server some path like that:

\some\some\some\some\mainSome

And for display it to front, I need only last path(mainSome).

And try to split it, but I can't.

```
 const path = '\some\some\some\some\mainSome'.split('\')
 //And also tried
 const path = '\some\some\some\some\mainSome'.split('\\')
```

And this didn't work.

Waiting for help from you

Comment: You do not have any backslashes in your strings there, just unnecessarily escaped normal `s` and `m` characters. If you get a string with literal backslashes, your second code should work

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
String.raw`\some\some\some\some\mainSome\`.split("\\");
```

Answer (score 1):

It's actually escaping the `s`s and `m`s in the string - you need to have a string with actual backslashes (escaped like `\\`):

```js
const path = "\\some\\some\\some\\some\\mainSome".split("\\").pop();
console.log(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok to add one more slash, it will work

```
 const path = '\\some\\some\\some\\some\\mainSome';
 const splitted = path.split('\\');
```

return the splitted variable gives you the array set.

Comment: I can't add any characters.

Answer (score -1):

You need to escape backslashes (with backslashes) in your string too;

```js
 const path = '\\some\\some\\some\\some\\mainSome'.split('\\');
 
 console.log(path);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const url = 'some/some/some/mainsom';
const a = url.split('/');
const aGet = a[a.length-1];
```